# Returned value solidity

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have a function in solidity

```
function calculate() external returns (bool) {
    return true;
}
```

But when I call it with hardhat I get this:

```
{
  hash: '0xa22571900e096215e636e1ef104e7606bab71e112a4ffa5922ad70904ef11e36',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  transactionIndex: null,
  confirmations: 0,
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x08', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x08', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x6f72', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0x99dBE4AEa58E518C50a1c04aE9b48C9F6354612f',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 137,
  data: '0xca77ab65',
  r: '0x762dadb2acf9580c24fd95f94a907902c908164ba669ac41faecbdc095fae70e',
  s: '0x02c3b28c03c8b5f48df177b91bb7b7ad95eef6b8e3d9c80c641511eb1650175b',
  v: 1,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 1337,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

I want to receive a simple `true` value, what is this? Is my value here? How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let the Ethereum know that you're just returning a value and you're not modifying the state, which does not require a transaction. To do this, mark your function as a pure function:

```
function calculate() external pure returns (bool) {
  return true;
}
```

in case you need to change the state you can emit an event and read the value from that event

[here](https://medium.com/txstreet/listening-to-events-in-hardhat-using-ethers-js-3e8c56b35aca) you have an example

```
  let contractWithSigner = contract.connect(wallet);

  let tx = await contractWithSigner.setGreeting("whats up!");
    
  await tx.wait();

  contract.on("GreeterEvent", (setter, NewGreeting, event) => {
    console.log("New Greeting is", NewGreeting);
  })
```

Comment: yeah, but I need to modify the state, that's the deal

Comment: I heard people solving this by emiting events

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question in order to show exactly what you are trying, but if you need a value from a transaction you can emit an event I have edited my answer